# Powershell: showing value only instead of @{} in result

Tags: powershell, output, display

I'm new to PWSH, it may looks easy for you guys but I can't find the way to show the result as expected.

```
$vm2 = Get-VM VM1234
$vmMemUsageAvg = get-VM $vm2.Name | Select @{N="Mem.Usage.Average";E={[Math]::Round((($_ |Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)-IntervalMins 5 -MaxSamples (12) |Measure-Object Value -Average).Average),2)}}
```

Now, as example, when requesting the result of `$vmMemUsageAvg` I receive this output:

```
C:\Windows\system32> $vmMemUsageAvg 
Mem.Usage.Average
-----------------
              5.9
```

but I want only want as output the value, like: 
5.9

putting that in Excel cell with

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 13) = [String]$vmMemUsageAvg
```

gives me a string like this:

```
@{Mem.Usage.Average=5.9}
```

Any help welcome to have this value ONLY displayed

Comment: putting that in Excel cell with 
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 13) = [String]$vmMemUsageAvg 
give me a string like this:
@{Mem.Usage.Average=5.9}

Comment: You have made an object with a property called 'Mem.Usage.Average' and a value of 5.9 in that property. To see just the value of that property, you have to ask for just that property. `$vmMemUsageAvg."Mem.Usage.Average"`. Yes, it's a bit silly to wrap 5.9 up in a property of an object, then unwrap it straight away afterwards.

Comment: Yes! I tried $vmMemUsageAvg.Mem.Usage.Average but wasn't successfull.
THE QUOTE MAKE IT WORK. THANKS !

Comment: @VinceD This is why you shouldn't include `.`'s in the names of properties. Without it quoted, it was looking in the a Mem property for the Usage property then into an Averaged property. Which is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Select-Object @{N="Mem.Usage.Average";E={...}}` you are making an object with a property `Mem.Usage.Average`, but it looks just want a string. So just take out the `Select`

```
$vm2 = Get-VM VM1234
$vmMemUsageAvg = [Math]::Round(((get-VM $vm2.Name | Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)-IntervalMins 5 -MaxSamples (12) | Measure-Object Value -Average).Average),2)
```